# Activity Selection with parallel activities

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, greedy

How to solve an activity scheduling(maximize the number of activities) problem having a total of n activities with k activities running in parallel. k < n , k can be 1,2,3,...n. k = 1 is the normal activity selection problem.  k = n is the trivial case. Will you use greedy approach or Dynamic programming to solve the same. NB - not an assignment question.

Comment: "Will you use greedy approach or Dynamic programming..." - what do you think, and why?

Comment: I have tried solving it using greedy. But I don't know if that's correct.